# "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

Tags: c#-4.0, websocket

I am trying to do some network programming with a simple client and a server that is given to me. When my client gets connected to the server ,server prints message "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

The port that I am using is 6000 and localhost is the host.

I am using a Tcp client.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleTankClientVersion1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netStream = null;

            //server ip
            String server = "127.0.0.1";

            //server port
            int servPort = 6000;

            //The input string is converted to a stream of bytes
            byte[] byteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("JOIN#");


            try
            {

                    // Create socket that is connected to server on port 6000
                    client = new TcpClient(server, servPort);

                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to server... sending join string");

                    netStream = client.GetStream();



                // Send the encoded string to the server
                netStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server...", byteBuffer.Length);

                int totalBytesRcvd = 0; // Total bytes received so far
                int bytesRcvd = 0; // Bytes received in last read

                // Receive the same string back from the server
                while (totalBytesRcvd < byteBuffer.Length)
                {
                    if ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(byteBuffer, totalBytesRcvd,
                    byteBuffer.Length - totalBytesRcvd)) == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection closed prematurely.");
                        break;
                    }
                    totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes from server: {1}", totalBytesRcvd,
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, totalBytesRcvd));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }




        }
    }
}
```

TcpTimedWaitDelay is 30 s
Max user port value is 60000

Comment: In case there is some problem with your code, could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28792359/edit) your question and add the relevant code you have?

Comment: @honk KK now i edited my post so as to include the code. Thanks

Comment: The error you are seeing only happens when multiple sockets try to bind to the same local IP/Port. There is no explicit binding in this code, so the client will use a random IP/Port chosen by the OS specifically to avoid this type of error. The only way this client code can get the error is if all possible ports are already in use, which is known as **port exhaustion**.

Comment: You said your server code (which you have not shown) is reporting the error, though. The server should be binding to a single port, and accepting all clients on that port. So the only way the server can get the error is if the server is trying to listen on an IP/Port that is already in use, before any clients connect to it.  It report the error after it has successfully opened the port, unless you are opening more ports in response to client activity, which you should not be doing (unless your protocol requires additional ports, like FTP does for example).

Comment: It is hard to diagnose your problem since you did not show your server code yet.